# PHP: Possible to access class after page loads via ajax?

Tags: php, class

I wasn't sure if when a class is instantiated with code in PHP, if is stays in the servers cache where it would be possible to access it with ajax (php file), or if it just dies once the script finishes running.

Is it possible to do this with a Keep-Alive connection or something?

I know I'm showing my ignorance in web handle, but at the risk of looking like an idiot, I had to ask.

Thanks!

Edit: Oh, was also wanting to know, could you store an object in sessions to be accessed?

Comment: At the end of the file's execution, it's done.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you feel that you need to keep this object around for an ajax call?  Have you considered using a separate PHP page to handle the ajax call?

Comment: Yeah, george, I would need a separate php file to make the ajax call, but I will need to access objects that were instantiated on the initial call.  I think Michael has it right.  Sessions (or cookies) is the way to go.

Comment: Cookies have little to do with this. They're bits of text sent between the browser and server, to maintain some state.

Comment: Yeah, but if you can store an object in a session variable, you could certainly do the same with a cookie.

Comment: Sure you could serialize to a cookie, but that'd be a serious WTF.  Session variables are server side, the session cookie is just an identifier that helps tie a particular request from the browser to the appropriate session information on the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store an object in $_SESSION, and do operations on it just like any other object (i.e.

```
$_SESSION['object']->method();
```

Comment: IMO, this is a bad idea. Keep your session variables as light as possible.  In fact, avoid sessions as much as possible.

Comment: George, would cookies be any better?  This is for admin's only, so site users wouldn't be affected by the Sessions as I'll only load them on login.

Comment: @Senica Gonzalez It depends on what you're doing.  If it's only used for an admin interface, then it's likely acceptable.  That said, one must still ask why?  If it's only for an admin interface, than what's the big deal w/ instantiating that object again for the ajax call?  I can't answer this question without knowing anything about the object in question.

Comment: I agree that it's less than ideal, especially because PHP's default behavior is to store session variables to disk, but there are situations where it could be the best solution, such as when instantiating the object is expensive.